# Как послать рест-запрос с одного приложения в другое?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Добрый день!

Я имею два модуля в одном приложении. Одно серверное, которое сделано на Spring Boot, другое клиентское, сделано на Vaadin.

Вопрос: как послать rest-запрос к серверному приложению(например по нажатию кнопки), используя интерфейсы rest контроллера(rest api, в котором определены rest endpoint)?

Пробовал делать через RestTemplate, но там проблема в том, что необходим URI для того, чтобы достучаться до rest endpointa(к примеру,  https://localhost:8080/books, а мне необходимо только /books).

Буду рад любому ответу!

Comment: это два разных приложения? развернутые на разных серверах?

Comment: не правильно объяснил, это 2 разных модуля в одном приложении, один из них, который сделан на Spring Boot регистрируется в Eureka, другой модуль, который сделан на Vaadin, не регистрируется в Eureka. Развернуты на одном сервере.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, есть какие-то идеи по этому вопросу?

Comment: у меня нет опыта с Vaadin. я бы такое делал на простом JavaScript.